# Sending POST request via Observable from angular to nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, observable

I have an Angular 5 application running and have configured ExpressJs as the backend, I'm running into a problem while trying to subscribe to an observable in Angular..  My angular application is running on localhost:4200 and my NodeJs application is running on localhost:3000.  I'm able to send a GET request from angular to node perfectly fine, but when I try to send a POST request with some data I get this error in the Chrome Dev Tools:

> Failed to load localhost:3000/user: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

It seems like angular isn't even sending the request because I can't see any activity in the terminal.  I've also tried sending a POST request to my Node application using curl in the terminal and it seems to work so I don't think it's a CORS problem, however a problem with my angular code.
Here is my code:
Angular Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}

       register(user: User) {
           const body = JSON.stringify(user);
           const headers = new Headers({ 'content-Type': 
           'application/json'});
           return this.http.post('localhost:3000/user/register', body, {headers: headers})
                    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                    .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));

    }

}
```

Angular Component:

```
onSubmit() {
    const user = new User(this.registrationForm.value.email,
                            this.registrationForm.value.password,
                            this.registrationForm.value.firstName,
                            this.registrationForm.value.lastName);
    this.authService.register(user)
                    .subscribe(
                        data => console.log(data),
                        error => console.log(error)
                    );
    this.registrationForm.reset();
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant at all but here is my backend code for this request:

```
router.post('/register', function(req,res,next){
    var user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
        email: req.body.email
    });
    user.save(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'Error while saving user',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'User created',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});
```

And I am properly setting my headers in Node:

```
app.options(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Thanks for any help you can give !!!  This is really giving me a headache :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failed to load localhost:3000/user: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

You’re just missing the `http:` protocol part from the request URL.

Replace this:

```
return this.http.post('localhost:3000/user', body, {headers: headers})
```

…with this:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user', body, {headers: headers})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are posting data to localhost:3000/user and listening to /register..

```
    @Injectable()
        export class AuthService {
            constructor(private http: Http){}

               register(user: User) {
                   const body = JSON.stringify(user);
                   const headers = new Headers({ 'content-Type': 
                   'application/json'});

                  // 'localhost:3000/user' change this to http://localhost:3000/user/register

                   return this.http.post('localhost:3000/user', body, {headers: headers})
                            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));

            }

        }
```